# Plot using python to check the number of elements occurring once, twice, thrice and so on in a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, visualization

I have a dataframe with 4 columns as:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ONFR.png)

I want to plot a bar chart where x-axis represents numbers 1,2,3..10 and y-axis represents the count of tracking id's occuring once, twice, thrice and so on against the x-axis.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please post your code parts with your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a test table below in the same format you have and you should be able to easily copy and paste it to see if it works for you now.

To make the plot you can groupby the `tracking_id` and count before using the built-in hist plot.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'tracking_id':['A','A','B','C','C'],
    'end_date':['2000','2001','2002','2003','2004'],
    'start_date':['1900','1901','1902','1903','1904'],
    'period_length':[1,2,3,4,5],
})
```

here is what the test table I made above looks like

[image]

```
df.groupby('tracking_id')['tracking_id'].count().plot.hist()
```

[image]